# save edit text value on changing radio button

Tags: android

I have two radio buttons in a radio group and three text edit fields in one layout.

Now when I switch radio button I would able to save data of edit text for pervious selected radio button and vice versa

Please help me.

Comment: where want to save and what exactly you want to save.?? please proper explain problem

Comment: i want to save start and end time for particular radio button for that time only  ..

Comment: its like a switch lets for radio1 start and end time is lets say 11 and 12 on change radio button edit text data will be remove and would able to add new data . when i change switch to radio button1 edit text data would be again 11 and 12 .. data would to save till the time that activity is running

Answer (score 0):

You can do using radio group.

```
     RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected

if(checkedId == R.id.radiobutton1)
{
//get data from edittext and save then clear edit text
}else
{
//get data from edittext and save then clear edit text
}

       }
    });
```

Comment: so for saving data what would be i use ? share preference ?

Comment: @AnkitaChopra its on you your data size and use of data. if is just one time use when user again add data and changed radio button you just want to replace older one value then you have to use sharedpref. else if you want to store all data then sqlite